# MainActivity has laked IntentReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-service

I have this error in the logcat: 
`Activity com.mypackage.app.MainActivity has laked IntentReceiver com.mypackage.app.MainActivity$100000000@4202adb8 that was originally registred here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`

The code of the service is:

```
package com.mypackage.app;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;

public static class UpdateService extends Service {    

public final static String TAG = "Bat";

    //private static final String TAG = AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.class.getSimpleName();
    public static Boolean debug     = true; 
        BatteryInfo mBI = null;     
        public void updateWidget(Context context, Intent batteryIntent){

            if (debug) Log.i(TAG,"---------- updateWidget");

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss ");

            RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.androidbatterywidget_layout);

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.level, "waiting!");

            final int status = batteryIntent.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);

            final int plugged = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);

            final int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.level, "" + level + " %" );

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.time, formatter.format(new Date()));

            final int temperature = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);

            String tempString= String.format("%.0f°C", new Float(temperature/10));

            if (debug) Log.d(TAG,"BAT:" + tempString + " " + level + "%");

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.temperature, tempString );

            final int voltage = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.voltage, "" + voltage + " mV" );


            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout ,

                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 

                            new Intent(context, AndroidBatteryActivity.class),Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));


            ComponentName myComponentName = new ComponentName(context, AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.class);

            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            manager.updateAppWidget(myComponentName, updateViews);


            //Second, update database in a thread       

            new Thread (new Runnable(){

                public void run(){

                    final Context c=getApplicationContext();

                    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(c);

                    db.record( level, status, plugged );

                    db.deleteOldEntries();

                    db.close();

                    if (debug) Log.i( TAG, "---------- Add record: " + level + " time: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() );   

                }
            }).start();


        }

        public void  handleCommand(Intent intent){

            if(mBI == null)

            {
                mBI = new BatteryInfo(this);

//              IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();

//              mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
//              registerReceiver(mBI, mIntentFilter);

                // After registering mBI, another update is immediately processed.

                // So, skip double update processing.
                return;

            } 
            //update widget views and database

            updateWidget(getApplicationContext(), intent);


        }


        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

            handleCommand(intent);            

        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            if (debug)

                Log.d(TAG, "----------------- onStartCommand");     

            handleCommand(intent);     

            // The service has to be running otherwise the broadcast ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED wont be received anymore

            // thats why it returns START_STICKY

            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();

            try{                
                if(mBI != null) {

                    if (debug)

                    Log.d(TAG, "----------------- onDestroy: unregisterReceiver(mBI)" );
                    unregisterReceiver(mBI);

                }

            }catch(Exception e)

            {Log.e(TAG, "", e);}

        }
        @Override

        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;

        }
    }   

}
```

I can't find the error.. I post the manifest too:

```
<service android:name=".UpdateService" /> 
        <receiver android:name=".BatteryInfo" android:label="BatteryInfo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" /> 
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidBatteryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" >
        </activity>
```

Any help?

Comment: You are registering a Receiver in your MainActivity programmatically and the code to unregister the same is either not there or it's not being called. That is when this exception appears. Share your MainActivity code, if possible.

Comment: the main activity has a button that call the service `public void batteryusage(View view){
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
     context.startService(intent);
}` Then the service call the `AndroidBatteryActivity` that call a graph activity. But when i click the button the application exit but there is no errors Only if i look at the logcat i see which i wrote. So what have i to do?I've taken the code from https://github.com/onlinux/AndroidBatteryWidget# and adapted in mine but i have this error.I try to create the UpdateService class and use it but nothing until now..

Comment: Do you see registerReceiver(..) being called anywhere in your code?

Comment: I can see you have commented that part to register the Receiver. In case you have done it deliberately, you might have to comment the line: unregisterReceiver(mBI); in your onDestroy too.

Comment: so just comment onDestroy?

Comment: Nothing..i can't understand..Look at this https://github.com/onlinux/AndroidBatteryWidget/blob/master/src/fr/free/onlinux/AndroidBatteryWidget/AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.java in the `AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider` class there is the onUpdate and onDisable methods that i don't have in my code. Is this the problem? Where have i to put them?

Comment: Just comment the line unregisterReceiver(mBI); in onDestroy and see it that works?

Comment: commenting line `unregisterReceiver(mBI);` doesn't work. The graph not starts but the logcat get the percentage, correct and the service is still going on even if the application is closed.. So the service goes.. The problem now i think is starting the activity of graph